# NSArray size and mutability

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In Java, I commonly initialize arrays that are a specific size and then add and replace objects as my code goes on. In Objective C, I can't do that with an NSArray. Code that I have ported over from Java often has to use NSMutableArray, which I assume perform less efficent than NSArray. (My best guess as to how NSMutableArray stores it's members is using a linked list, but I could be wrong)

Are there any types of arrays for Objective C that have fixed sizes and allow changes within the array? Why is it not possible to replace objects at a certain object with NSArray? I can do this with C arrays, why not Objective C?

Comment: Objective-C is just a superset of C. You can use C arrays if you want to. Still, why do you assume that it is slower? How have you tested it?

Comment: I'd also not dismiss NSMutableArray. It is widely used, and unless you can measure a performance problem, you could probably just go with it.

Comment: CFMutableArray (toll-free bridged from NSMutableArray) guarantees O(log N) access time. This can't be a linked list.

Comment: When going from Java to Cocoa, replace your Lists with NSMutableArray, both conceptually and in code. The equivalent of a Java Array proper is a C array, from which the Java one itself came, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, `NSMutableArray` won't be any slower than a plain `NSArray`.

`NSMutableArray` is not going to use a linked list, it will use a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).  It is every bit as fast as a plain array except on the insertions where it needs to resize.  But since those get exponentially further apart, it amortizes to nearly the same, and identical if you don't hit a resize.

It's basically the same as Java's `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks! But what happens when I insert an object and the adjacent memory is already allocated?

Comment: If the adjacent memory is already allocated, the next bigger array will be allocated elsewhere and the values will be copied over.  That's the worst case situation, but the proof of amortized O(1) assumes this worst-case behavior.  That one call will be slower, but that happens more rarely as the array gets bigger (only one O(n) call every n calls makes it O(1)).

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, many classes have mutable and immutable variants.There may be performance or memory benefits to immutable NSArrays, but if you require an array that can be modified, simply use an NSMutableArray. There's no reason to be alarmed or concerned. That's what they're there for.

You can initialize mutable arrays with intended capacities, though you are not forever bound to that capacity - the array will grow beyond capacity if necessary.

```
int numberOfItems = ...
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfItems];
```

Any optimization benefit available to NSArray is contingent on the fact that it is immutable. So syntax aside, you can't realize the benefits of an immutable object when what you need to actually use is mutable (eg, you need to replace objects in your case).

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume `NSMutableArray` is too slow for you.  Profile, don't speculate.

You might also check out [`NSPointerArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPointerArray) if you're developing a Mac OS X app.  It's not available on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `NSMutableArray` if you want to replace a certain object. And create the array using

```
 + (id)arrayWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems
```

or

```
- (id)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems
```

of `NSMutableArray` and specify the size of the array.