# Are Mutable classes "heavier?"

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, mutable

On some intuitive (perhaps wrong) idea of performance, I always get a `copy` of a mutable instance before I store it. So if a property expects an `NSArray` I take the mutable array I'm working with and store it as `self.array = mutableArray.copy` (though the property is specified as `strong` or `retain`).

This seems silly to me, suddenly, but is it? Do mutable instances -- doing the exact same task -- perform the same?

**Note:** The mutable instance falls out of scope and (thanks to ARC) gets released right after this, so there's no worry that it'll be mutated once it's assigned to the property.

Comment: It's not very clear what do you mean under “heavier". When copying the mutable objects, the new instance is created. When copying the immutable only retain count increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are both (as far as I'm aware) implemented on top of [CFArray](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.43/CFArray.c), which simply has a flag specifying whether it's mutable. `CFArray` functions which require a mutable array have an assertion right at the beginning, checking that flag:

```
void CFArraySetValueAtIndex(CFMutableArrayRef array, CFIndex idx, const void *value) {
    // snip...
    CFAssert1(__CFArrayGetType(array) != __kCFArrayImmutable, __kCFLogAssertion, "%s(): array is immutable", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

Mutable and immutable `CFArray`s are identical other than passing or failing this assertion, and so should `NSArray`s and `NSMutableArray`s be, performance- or other-wise.

Comment: Great stuff. What about `NSData` and `NSString`? I'd imagine it's the same story.

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly, that's true. Any Cocoa class that's "toll-free bridged" is basically an ObjC wrapper around a Core Foundation type, and all the CF types I've looked at have the flag and mutability check. The code for Core Foundation is all on http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/

Comment: The real question is how one can know what source to look at for what? Where would I learn that the Cocoa classes are wrappers for the CF Types, and... aren't there versions of these things? Don't they change?

Comment: @Yar: Well, like I said, the "toll-free bridging", which is noted in the docs for a Cocoa class, is a strong indicator. How that works, by RidiculousFish: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html By "versions", do you mean versions of Core Foundation, or something else?

Comment: @Matt: My [mind was blown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863510/nsset-implementation/5863615#comment6739909_5863615) when it was pointed out to me. It's one of those "How in the _hell_ did I not know about this before?!" things.

Comment: Amazing post, thanks @JoshCaswell. However, I was kind of hoping for something from Apple where this stuff is explained in an official capacity. The opaqueness of the entire platform -- er, um, whatever you call it, Obj-C + iOS -- is frustrating. "Blind men and an elephant" type of information, all spread out between StackOverflow and developer.apple.com... By versions I meant versions of the bridging and of the CF Types, etc. I understand that it's private, but is it secret?

Comment: @Yar: Which individual types are bridged to which classes is public information. There's a chart in an ObjC document: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html and also in a Core Foundation doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html Core Foundation (C code) and Foundation (ObjC code) are kept in sync AFAIK, but only _Core_ Foundation is open source. I'm not sure there's much more official information.

Comment: @Yar: Hope that's helpful. If there's more info you want, let me know and I'll answer if I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's been very helpful as usual @JoshCaswell. I'll continue to investigate and see what I can learn. In other news, looking at your "mind was blown" link above, I learned that the `copy` method of inmutable instances would be much faster than the `copy` method of mutable instances, since it just adds a retain. I know this is probably not relevant in most contexts, but it is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Partly answered here: [NSArray size and mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252417/nsarray-size-and-mutability)

NSMutableArray is not noticeably slower or larger (memory-wise) than an NSArray. It's basically just an NSArray that reallocates itself when it gets full as as bigger array, and keeps doing that as you add items to it.

The reason for copying mutable arrays as immutable ones when assigning them to values in your class is so you can guarantee that their values don't change. If you store a mutable array in your class, other code can change its values outside of your class without calling any of your methods. That leaves you vulnerable to crashes due to internal inconstancy errors within your classes.

For example, supposing that when the array was set, you cached the length of the array as an int property in your class. That would be fine if the array was immutable, but if it was mutable, someone else could change the array, and your cached value would now be wrong, but you have no way of knowing that.

However, it's not necessary to do the copying manually. If you declare your array properties as:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *foo;
```

Then whenever you assign an array to object.foo, it will automatically be copied. You don't need to copy it again yourself. It's best practice to use a property type of copy instead of strong/retain for any type that has a mutable variant, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *foo;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *foo;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *foo;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *foo;
etc...
```

However be careful not to use it for mutable properties, or it will make an immutable copy stored in a property that thinks it's mutable and cause a crash if you try to mutate it. The synthesised copy property isn't smart enough to use mutableCopy automatically.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *foo; //don't do this
```

Comment: Thanks Nick +1. It's a good answer, but 70% of it (in bulk) is orthogonal to the question at hand (everything after third paragraph, first sentence).

Comment: It seemed relevant because your question implied that you thought the reason for converting mutable arrays to immutable ones by copying was for performance reasons, whereas actually it's for code security. You also implied that you might be doing extra work by always copying objects when the property is of type retain, and I was explaining that by using a property of type copy you can avoid that extra work, which may actually have a (small) performance benefit as you avoid an extra retain/release each time you assign.

Comment: Fair enough, Nick. Personally, I think that taking an `NSArray` property and calling mutable methods on it because you "know" it's mutable would be suicidal. So to me, the copy isn't necessary: just  declaring the property to be `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray` is sufficient. But for true security, I guess you could mark it as `copy`, which would be better than manually copying.

Comment: That's not the issue. Whichever code "gave" your class the array doesn't know that you are treating it as immutable, so is perfectly justified in mutating it's own copy (which is defined as mutable) without knowing that it is also mutating the one inside your class because you retained it instead of copying it.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity you're asking if, given an NSArray and an NSMutableArray both subjected to a battery of non-mutating test methods, does the NSArray perform noticeably faster? I specify non-mutataing, because it looks like you're copying a mutable array to an immutable array with the belief that the immutable array will perform its non-mutating methods faster than the mutable array. Anyways, the answer is no. (But don't take my word for it; profile).

Even if NSMutableArray overrode some non-mutating methods (which we can't know about, one way or another), you wouldn't need to worry about it. Adding a couple CPU cycles is trivial compared to the overall computational complexity of the operation. As long as NSMutableArray doesn't manage to turn a O(n) lookup-operation into a O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation, you'll be fine 99% of the time. (Those complexities are just fictitious examples).

While there are perfectly valid reasons why you might want to copy a mutable array into an immutable array (as pointed out by @NickLockwood), performance shouldn't be one of them. Premature optimization is very bad, after all.